# Item not deleting in sharepoint designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I was trying to update and delete items from multiple list based on sharepoint when an item is added to a master list. I was able to update a list but cannot delete an entry from a different list. please see below for more details.

I can see the workflow is still running.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use the ID of the item - then you're eliminating the risk of string matching. Change the field in the lookup to ID and change the return field of the lookup to ID as well. Then you should be fine (provided the user does in fact have rights to delete the item, if thats not the case you need to place the delete part in an app step).

[image]

Comment: ID is different for different list know ?. I have tried it with PartID as a test which gives the result as well.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question?

Comment: StockID_PurchaseDate is a calculated column in the StockItems list and the same field is added as a lookup field to the "Printers Consumable Requests" list where the workflow runs. I doubt if there is string mismatch. i even checked with different fields and permissions.

Comment: If you use a lookup already there absolutely no reason not to match by id rather than a string.

Like I said change the field to be ID when you're deleting. And when setting the value take the id (As opposed to the text) from the lookup field on the item and your all set.

Comment: Just one questions though - are you trying to delete multiple items within the same list here? if that's the case you need to add a loop to iterate through all the matching items.

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand ID of stock item that needs to be deleted is 6031 but at the same time ID if the one inserted to the "Printers Consumable Request" is 4433. how will i match it

Comment: I have updated my answer with an image to explain it. What it does is to take the ID from the lookup column and match it to the ID of the item.

Comment: Glad to help :)